# Issue when configuring Docker mysql instance with 'tables' node module

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker

I was trying to connect to a mysql instance run by docker engine:

> docker run --name mysql_new -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin -p 3306:3306
>   -d mysql

I am able to see the connection in mysql_workbench.

Now, I am trying to run below command on mac terminal.

> tables -i server/data/some.csv
>   --db=“mysql://root:admin@localhost/db_name” --batch-size=20

But I get below error:

```
TABLES
▇▇▇▇▇▇

Model guessing
▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀
• No models options provided, guessing data structure and types from first 1000 rows
• Streaming: server/data/some.csv
• Parser: csv
• [ ] 100% | 0.0s elapsed | ~0.0s left
• Done guessing

Database
▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀
• Connecting to DB
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/tables/lib/tables.js:541
if (this.dbConnectionConfg.protocol.toLowerCase().indexOf("mysql") === 0 ||
^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of null
at Tables.dbConnect (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/tables/lib/tables.js:541:39)
at Tables.wrapper [as dbConnect] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/tables/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4941:19)
at Tables.start (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/tables/lib/tables.js:158:8)
at Tables.wrapper [as start] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/tables/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4941:19)
at ReadStream.streamDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/tables/lib/tables.js:439:18)
at ReadStream.emit (events.js:165:20)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1101:12)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:152:19)
```

Opened an issue as well here:
https://github.com/datanews/tables/issues/13

Comment: have you created some db in the mysql? in your url is some default name, i would also include port number

Comment: Yes of course, I did with the exact db name I am passing here with the port 3306. I can able to connect to the mysql db server started by docker mysql instance, but not able to connect from tables node_module.

If I do the same normally without using a docker mysql instance, I am able to use tables module properly. @MazelTov